# How do I install Yeoman on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, nodejs, 19.04, npm

I am having a hard time figuring out what I should do to install Yeoman on Ubuntu 19.04.

What is the recommended procedure for installing on my personal laptop that nobody else uses? Ideally a reasonably recent but stable version.

The [official documentation](https://yeoman.io/) suggests `npm install -g yo` but I get permission errors, and apparently running as `sudo` is a bad idea.

I am new to yeoman/npm/node. In answers, please say in what directory each command should be run, since apparently some commands are sensitive to the current directory or even write files in the current directory.

Comment: In 19.10 the issue is not happening. Btw did you insall node and npm with sudo?

Comment: @LordDraagon: Sorry I don't remember... would you mind quickly posting how you successfully installed node/npm/yeoman? Thanks :-)

Comment: Actually, I just did a simple `npm install yo`. However, I installed `npm` and `node` using nvm. When you install using nvm you don't need `sudo`

Comment: The average yeoman user around me has never installed `node`, and has never heard about `npm`. An answer simply listing the commands to type on an out-of-the-box Ubuntu to get Yeoman running would be helpful to many, I think:-)